# What are you doing up at this late hour?

Tags: adverbial-phrases

> What are you doing up at this late hour?

Can I rewrite the sentence above as below?

> (Being) Up at this late hour, what are you doing?

Comment: 'Up' is used informally as a synonym for 'awake' in your example.  So, the sentence isn't just asking what 'you' are doing 'at this late hour,' it's asking why you're *awake* 'at this late hour.'  'Up' changes the sentence's meaning, and so can't be omitted.

Comment: Your title and question body ask whether "up" is needed, but the question body also asks whether the sentence can be rewritten in a different form without changing "up". Which is your actual question? (If you'd like to ask both questions, then please post them separately, since they involve different issues.)

Comment: @MarcInManhattan EDIT performed according to your suggestion.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey 'up' here means adjective or adverb? I guess it's adjective or both.

Comment: 'Up at this time' here just means 'out of bed at this time', The time could be surprisingly late (past someone's normal or expected bed time) or the time is surprisingly early (before someone's normal or expected time of getting up).

Comment: In speech, we often flip things around. We often flip things around in speech.

Comment: @Lambie what do you think is the part of speech of 'up' in the example: What are you doing up at  this late hour? In my perspective, 'What are you doing?' itself makes perfect sentence structure, so I think 'up' is more likely to be an adverb.

Comment: to be up means to not be sleeping; it's an idiom.

Comment: This question borders on proofreading. If you have a question about some aspect of English in general, please [edit] the question to ask it

Comment: @gotube It's not a proofreading. It's a question about changing  the location of an adverbial phrase.

Answer (score 3):

I would not rewrite it that way. In general, modifiers should be as close as possible to what they modify; that is especially useful for avoiding ambiguity. In your rewritten sentence, the modifier "(Being) Up at this late hour" is closest to the pronoun "what", even though it clearly does not describe that pronoun. It is certainly possible that a listener will infer that it describes "you", but a listener might also infer that it describes the speaker. I wouldn't risk the possibility of being misunderstood; the first sentence is much more natural and easily understood.